# ng-bind-html is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've put a JSfiddle here so you can see code that is actually working...

http://jsfiddle.net/vtKqG/1/

Unfortunately this does not work on my local machine even though everything else does (I have other angular code running fine).

On my local machine I only see my html in the output if i use..

```
ng-bind-html-unsafe="message.content"
```

instead of...

```
ng-bind-html="message.content"
```

So, on JSfiddle it works when I leave the "unsafe" off, but on my local machine the unsafe has to be there, which seems undesirable from a security point of view.

I am loading the same version of Angular and sanitize, in the same order and my code I think is identical, only the environment seems to be different.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you forget to load the ngSanitize module? var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

Comment: One other thing. ngSanitize is in a different javascript file. Did you load it in your page?

Comment: Yep, it's loaded and working, otherwise the unsafe version wouldn't work. It only stops working (blank output) when I remove the -unsafe

Comment: Is this your output? http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/35fJE/

Comment: Yes, the div is rendered but empty as in your example. I see you changed ngSanitize to just ng when injecting into the module. Mine is correct however, I copied and pasted directly from the working fiddle.

Comment: Did you load angular-sanitize.js in the correct order (after angular.js)?

Comment: Yeah, version 1.0.3 from google APIs, followed by sanitize version 1.0.3 from the same source, followed by my local file javascript/controllers.js

Comment: Like I say, I think it's all being loaded correctly because it works when i use -unsafe. The safe version produces an empty div tag though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21734/discussion-between-asgoth-and-jonhobbs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add your module to ng-app:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
...
```

If you don't specify this, angular will only load module 'ng', not ng-sanitize. ng-bind-unsafe is in module ng, not ng-sanitize, which is why this accidently worked.

Comment: Thank you asgoth, and thanks for taking the time to help me in the chat room :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in new version of AngularJS 1.2+ they change it, since then you have to use trustAsHtml() method to disable Html escaping.

[Solution can be find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)