# With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to use `$sanitize` provider and the `ng-bind-htm-unsafe` directive to allow my controller to inject HTML into a DIV.

However, I can't get it to work.

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{preview_data.preview.embed.html}}"></div>
```

I discovered that it is because it was removed from AngularJS (thanks).

But without `ng-bind-html-unsafe`, I get this error:

http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$sce/unsafe

Comment: There is a simple solution for 1.2.23+, [see post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25679834/1812732)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35813932/572180

Answer (score 124, accepted):

1. You need to make sure that sanitize.js is loaded. For example, load it from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/[LAST_VERSION]/angular-sanitize.min.js
2. you need to include `ngSanitize` module on your `app`
   eg: `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);`
3. you just need to bind with `ng-bind-html` the original `html` content. No need to do anything else in your controller. The parsing and conversion is automatically done by the `ngBindHtml` directive. (Read the `How does it work` section on this: [$sce](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ng/service/$sce)). So, in your case `<div ng-bind-html="preview_data.preview.embed.html"></div>` would do the work.

Comment: It is the cleanest option to do that safely. It came with more dependencies but it's about safety so no hesitation !

Comment: Using this with ionic 1.0.0-beta.13

Comment: This doesn't work with some tags, like input.  Of course there's no easy way to get around this.  Really frustrating.

Comment: Most common and secure way. Prefer this if you will plan use bind-html in diferent views.

Answer (score 357):

Instead of declaring a function in your scope, as suggested by Alex, you can convert it to a simple filter :

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);
```

Then you can use it like this :

```
<div ng-bind-html="preview_data.preview.embed.html | to_trusted"></div>
```

And here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/leeroy/6j4Lg/1/

Comment: I have a small collection of useful tools for angular on [github](https://github.com/capaj/ng-tools), I will include this filter in those tools if you won't mind. This is IMHO the best solution when you trust the html.

Comment: @Capaj No problem, but if you add a link to this answer this would be greatly appreciated. :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21254635

Comment: Very nice. this works like a charm on nested repeats!

Comment: This seems like a MUCH better solution than coding for each controller. Just a quick filter and done!  I used it with repeating table rows, simple as pie....  `<td ng-bind-html="representative.primary | to_trusted"></td>`

Comment: angular.module('myApp').filter('trustAsHtml', ['$sce', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml }]);

Comment: Every solution that involves blessing the HTML as trusted introduces a XSS vulnerability. Please see the answer suggesting ngSanitize below (stackoverflow.com/a/25679834/22227) for a safer fix.

Answer (score 275):

You indicated that you're using Angular 1.2.0... as one of the other comments indicated, `ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated.

Instead, you'll want to do something like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="preview_data.preview.embed.htmlSafe"></div>
```

In your controller, inject the `$sce` service, and mark the HTML as "trusted":

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
  // ...
  $scope.preview_data.preview.embed.htmlSafe = 
     $sce.trustAsHtml(preview_data.preview.embed.html);
}
```

Note that you'll want to be using 1.2.0-rc3 or newer.  (They fixed [a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3932) in rc3 that prevented "watchers" from working properly on trusted HTML.)

Comment: I tried using the above but it breaks my code.  Seems you need to prepend '$scope' before the function definition -- perhaps it was "understood" at one time, but no longer.  The following should work: `myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {`

Comment: You can look more information about $sce [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) just to pursue curiosity! ;)

Comment: Note that this will likely cause an XSS security issue in your code. See the answer suggesting `ngSanitize` below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25679834/22227) for an alternative, safer fix.

Comment: Why this is a bad idea: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1fBwDABfa2RdWxSFwadq8qD7soDIcqGzSvANkm1nlNas/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.g103580afa1_1_851

Comment: `trustAsHtml` does what it says, it trusts *any* incoming html code, which can result in Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks

Answer (score 114):

For me, the simplest and most flexible solution is:

```
<div ng-bind-html="to_trusted(preview_data.preview.embed.html)"></div>
```

And add function to your controller:

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
}
```

Don't forget add `$sce` to your controller's initialization.

Comment: Seems more straightforward to have the controller returned the trusted html in $scope

Comment: This can throw infinite loop on $sce, do something like: $scope.trusted = {};
    $scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
        return $scope.trusted[html_code] || ($scope.trusted[html_code] = $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code));
    };

Comment: Every solution that involves blessing the HTML as trusted introduces a XSS vulnerability. Please see the answer suggesting ngSanitize below (stackoverflow.com/a/25679834/22227) for a safer fix.

Answer (score 69):

The best solution to this in my opinion is this:

1. Create a custom filter which can be in a common.module.js file for example - used through out your app:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('common.module', []);

   // html filter (render text as html)
   app.filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
       return function (text) {
           return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
       };    
   }])
   ```
2. Usage:

   ```
   <span ng-bind-html="yourDataValue | html"></span>
   ```

Now - I don't see why the directive `ng-bind-html` does not `trustAsHtml` as part of its function - seems a bit daft to me that it doesn't

Anyway - that's the way I do it - 67% of the time, it works ever time.

Comment: You can use the following regex to do a find and replace:
regex: ng-bind-html-unsafe="((?:(?!").)*)"
replacement: ng-bind-html="($1) | html"
with the above filter.

Comment: Every solution that involves blessing the HTML as trusted introduces a XSS vulnerability. Please see the answer suggesting ngSanitize below (stackoverflow.com/a/25679834/22227) for a safer fix.

Answer (score 7):

You can create your own simple unsafe html binding, of course if you use user input it could be a security risk.

```
App.directive('simpleHtml', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.simpleHtml, function (value) {
      element.html(scope.$eval(attr.simpleHtml));
    })
  };
})
```

Comment: Couldn't this directive also use the `$sce.trustAsHtml`?

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to use {{ }} inside of ng-bind-html-unsafe:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="preview_data.preview.embed.html"></div>
```

Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/R7JmGIo4xcJoBc1v4iki?p=preview

The {{ }} operator is essentially just a shorthand for ng-bind, so what you were trying amounts to a binding inside a binding, which doesn't work.

Comment: However, if I remove it, I get nothing injected. And the docs are highly confusing, using a single } http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Comment: Very odd. I've just tested it to be sure and for me it worked as expected. I agree the single { } are a bit confusing in the docs, but they're meant as a representation of an expression, not as literals in the string. I've updated my answer with a working plunk.

Comment: Also, if you're using 1.2.0 already, see the comments here as ng-bind-html-unsafe has been removed: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml

Comment: I am using 1.2. :( Grrr! How can one inject unsafe HTML? I get this error without it: http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$sce/unsafe

Comment: The `{{}}` operator was causing my issue with binding failing, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem. Still couldn't get content from my markdown files hosted on github.

After setting up a whitelist (with added github domain) to the $sceDelegateProvider in app.js it worked like a charm.

Description: Using a whitelist instead of wrapping as trusted if you load content from a different urls.

**Docs:** [$sceDelegateProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sceDelegateProvider) and [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) (for fetching, compiling and including external HTML fragment)

Answer (score 2):

Strict Contextual Escaping can be disabled entirely, allowing you to inject html using `ng-html-bind`.  This is an unsafe option, but helpful when testing.

Example from the [AngularJS documentation on `$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce):

```
angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
  // Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
  // Do not use in new projects.
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

Attaching the above config section to your app will allow you inject html into `ng-html-bind`, but as the doc remarks:

> SCE gives you a lot of security benefits for little coding overhead.
>   It will be much harder to take an SCE disabled application and either
>   secure it on your own or enable SCE at a later stage. It might make
>   sense to disable SCE for cases where you have a lot of existing code
>   that was written before SCE was introduced and you're migrating them a
>   module at a time.

Comment: Good to know about, but definitely something that should be handled with care.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter like this

```
angular.module('app').filter('trustAs', ['$sce', 
    function($sce) {
        return function (input, type) {
            if (typeof input === "string") {
                return $sce.trustAs(type || 'html', input);
            }
            console.log("trustAs filter. Error. input isn't a string");
            return "";
        };
    }
]);
```

usage

```
<div ng-bind-html="myData | trustAs"></div>
```

it can be used for other resource types, for example source link for iframes and other types declared [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAs)