# Angular-ui-bootstrap typehead not working with AngularJS 1.2.0-rc3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is a working example of Angular-ui-bootstrap typehead working with AngularJS 1.0.5:
http://plnkr.co/edit/me20JzvukYbK0WGy6fn4

The template uses ng-bind-html-unsafe witch is deprecated in AngularJS 1.2.0-rc3.

How can I bind html unsafe in that template? I would have used ng-bind but the filter typeaheadHighlight:query adds  tags in match.model.title.

Thanks!

Comment: See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: Thanks but this is an Angular-ui-bootstrap compatibility issue more than an AngularJS one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS removed the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` tag in its 1.2RC version which breaks the default typeahead template. But you have at least 2 ways to work-around it:

1. Move to the version 0.6.0 of the angular-ui/bootstrap library that has an equivalent tag named `bind-html`, here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/D84pG1WwutE4lRU46FIs?p=preview
2. Include the `ngSanitize` module and use AngularJS built-in `ng-bind-html` directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/9Q2Zp3BTQbstv9AjvVg4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's flawless. I was actually using the latest version of angular-ui-bootstrap but with ng-bind-html-unsafe directive instead of bind-html-unsafe. May be useful to someone :)