# AngularJS load tabbed content directive dynamicly

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-directive

I have a tabbed navigtion in my webapp that looks like this
 [image]

Now I want to Change the directive each time the user clicks on one of the Navigation points. My Idea was to init the page with the first template.

```
$scope.currentDirective = $compile('<div order-Sale></div>');
```

Then when the user clicks on a tab, I wanted to change and compile the content again with a new directive in it. But for some reason this is not working. How would you proceed in order to archive this dynamic content loading? I really want to only  load the content on necessary need and not just to show or hide it. I think using directives is the right way to go for it, but I'm a but stuck at the implementation... Someone any pointer ? (I don't want to use any jQuery)

What I tried [Edit]:

The **controller.js**

```
    app.controller('pageController',['$scope','$compile', function($scope, $compile){

      var templates = ['<div first-template></div>','<div second-template></div>'];

      $scope.currentTemplate = $compile(templates[0]);

      $scope.changeTemplate = function(id) {

        $scope.currentTemplate = $compile(templates[id]);

      };

  }]);
```

The **HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="pageController">
    <li>
        <a ng-click="changeTemplate('1')">Change Template</a>
    </li>
    {{currentTemplate}}
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code and show what you tried.

Comment: Added what I've tested

Comment: I updated my answer. When you ask questions, please avoid `for some reason this is not working` and provide a code example instead, so it can be reproduced . It will save everyone lots of time and misunderstanding. Let the code explain why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

- **$compile** returns a linking function **not a value**, you cannot just bind it to your template with interpolation.
- You should use [ngBindHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml) instead of regular bindings ( `ngBind` & `{{ }}` ).
- **ngBindHtml** does compiling, linking and watching all out-of-the-box.
- [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsIrVU1iJUzNjOoSyCqi?p=preview)

```
  app.controller('pageController',['$scope','$compile','$sce', function($scope, $compile, $sce){
    var templates = ['<div>first-template</div>','<div>second-template</div>'];
    $scope.currentTemplate = $sce.trustAsHtml(templates[0]);
    $scope.changeTemplate = function(id) {
      $scope.currentTemplate = $sce.trustAsHtml(templates[id]);
    };
  }]);
```

The markup:

```
  <div ng-controller="pageController">
    <button ng-click="changeTemplate('1')">Change Template</button>
    <div ng-bind-html="currentTemplate"></div>
  </div>
```

---

#### For more robust dynamic content loading you have two good alternatives:

- [ngRoute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) from angular team.
- [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) from angular-ui team.

If you want to change and compile the content again, well that's exactly what `ng-view`*/* `ui-view` directives already do for you.

#### Why not just use a directive:

- You probably need to load a different template (html partial) for each tab.
- You probably need to change the url based on the tab (and vice versa)
- You probably need to instantiate a different controller for each tab.
- `ngRoute` and `ui-router` come with their own directives.
- You can implement your own route module if you want but that's more than just a directive.

Comment: I just want to update the directive to another one or change the template of the directive. Not to change the whole view.