# accordion with ng-repeat and ng-bind-html won't work

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to use accordion and html content in this way:

```
<accordion>
   <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in items">
      <accordion-heading>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-elenco">
         <img postsrc="img/flag/flag_{{item.index}}.jpg">
      </a>
      </accordion-heading>
      <p ng-bind-html="item.content"></p>
   </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

AND

```
var items = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
var content = "<div>TEST</div>";
items.push({index:i,content:content});
}
$scope.items = items;

var app = angular.module('MyApp',['ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap']);
```

Accordion works but html isn't rendered into p tag.

What could be the problem?

EDIT

If i try something like:

```
<div ng-bind-html="to_trusted(item.content)"></div>
```

And add function to controller:

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code)
    {
    console.log(html_code);
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
    }
```

Nothing changes and in console i get many "undefined"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the HTML content is declared unsafe by Angular due to it's [Strict Contextual Escaping](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce).

Another SO answer already explains clearly how this can be solved: [HTML injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19417443/3233450), that is if you are using Angular version 1.2.0 or up.

I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bbkNGJRiLeWwKBTKwPWv) to match your case.

Comment: What angular version do you use? I replicated your code in the Plunkr and it works. Can you perhaps construct a Plunkr with your code?

Comment: i'm using AngularJS v1.2.9