# Angular Js - html rendering in angular treeview directive

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am using angular treeview directive to show treeview.
I am unable to render html. 
for eg. **B** is showing as `<b>B</b>`.

here is the fiddle
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deveshsinghal22/vL4TJ/74/)

i have used ng-html-bind for html rendering many times, but its not working here.

Comment: What version of Angular JS are you using. In Angular 1.2.0 ng-bind-html-unsafe has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks in treeview's code, by default you can't.

But you can modify it's code (example for minified version), change

```
<span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="'+a+'.selectNodeLabel(node)">{{node.'+e+'}}</span>
```

to

```
<span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="'+a+'.selectNodeLabel(node)" ng-bind-html-unsafe="node.'+e+'">
```

Don't forget to add ngSanitize module to your app: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

**Upd:** Here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vL4TJ/76/

Answer (score 4):

As  `ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated now, you will need to use $sce.trustAsHtml. There is a [nice article](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to understand what $sce is.

For quick reference you can also refer to [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html).

Comment: but how to use this with directive?
http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

there is no option for using ng-bind-html-unsafe or any other

Comment: There is angular version 1.0.6 used in fiddle. I don't think angular has $sce since that time.

Comment: oops , @gorpacrate : Nice catch. I was trying to modifying the fiddle, but no avail. You mentioned the reason. Thanks.