# allow rendering of html inside angular's square brakets

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

suppose I have this bit of html and javascript:

```
$scope.test = "hello<br/>world";
<div>{{ test }}</div>
```

angular will obviously render it as:

```
<div>hello<br/>world</div>
```

and that is exactly how it is supposed to work but, what if I would like it to actually render it as html markup rather than text?

I know this can lead to security problems, but I would just like to know out of curiousity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a filter as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html):

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="my_html | to_trusted"></div>
</div>
```

This is how your javascript would appear:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.my_html = '<div>hello<br/>world</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive in AngularJS.

```
<div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
 <p ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></p>
</div>
```

where

```
$scope.myHTML = "I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#">links!</a>"
```

will be rendered accordingly.

For the security concerns involved in this, before you pass the HTML content to your scope variable myHTML, sanitize it with:

```
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
```

and then use $scope.trustedHtml in your ng-bind-html directive as listed above.

Comment: i get an error: Error: $sce:unsafe
Require a safe/trusted value