# How to bind text as a DOM object in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I want to show `MathML` DOM object dynamically with `Angularjs`.

This is what I wrote:

```
var mathML = angular.module('mathML', ['ngSanitize']);

mathML.controller('mathMLCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.result = function(){
    return "<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><msup><msqrt><mrow><mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi></mrow></msqrt><mn>27</mn></msup></math>";
    //return "<p>p tag</p>";
  };
}]);
```

With `ng-bind-html`, I can insert text as a HTML text, but `MathML`'s XML is not inserted properly. (All tags are deleted.)

It looks like necessary to insert `MathML` text as DOM Objects. But I don't know how to do it.

How can I show `MathML` with `Angularjs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-bind-html sanitizes the output by removing tags that are not listed as "safe". The math tag is not listed under the allowed tags. If you trust this html to never have exploits, you'll want to use the $sce service to mark the code as trusted. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19417443/1248889

Another alternative would be to save this text as a partial, in it's own separate file. Then in your html, use ng-include to load the partial into the dom.