# Angular.js parse html tags in JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-filters

Is it possible to parse html tags in a JSON value? Possibly through a filter? I have the following JSON.

```
{
    "title" : "Auto Donation Program",
    "shortname" : "auto_donation_program",
    "summary": "Donated vehicles find new homes through this program. Recipients are eligible to apply if they have been actively participating at Vineyard Cincinnati or The Healing Center under the guidelines of the program for six months.",
    "description" : "<h2>Give your automobile to a new home to help a family in need</h2><p>Please contact Deena Casagrande at (513) 346-4080 Ext. 207 to make arrangements for auto donations. Please do not drop your car off in the parking lot.</p><h2>Tax Benefits</h2><p>It seems that every non-profit these days is encouraging you to donate your vehicle to charity and \"get a tax deduction.\" But there’s a simple distinction between donating your car to The Healing Center versus donating it almost anywhere else.</p><p>As of January 1, 2005, the rules on how much you can write off your taxes were tightened. If the organization sells your car, as most do, you can deduct only the amount they sold it for--and they may sell it for far less than it’s worth. However, if the organization gives your car to someone who will drive it, as The Healing Center does, you can claim full Blue Book value--a significant difference on your taxes. (It’s important to note that when you donate a vehicle, you receive a tax deduction, not a tax credit.)</p><h2>So where does your car end up? </h2><p>Those on the receiving end of The Healing Center’s auto donation program must fill out a detailed questionnaire, meet the eligibility requirements of the program, and be approved by the Benevolence Review Team. Vehicles are given to single parent families or individuals needing transportation for employment or who are enrolled in school to obtain employment.</p>"
  }
```

Displayed in my template as:

```
<p>{{service.description}}</p>
```

Comment: see the accepted example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<div ng-bind-html="'{{service.description}}' | to_trusted"></div>
```

Filter

```
angular.module('app')
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```