# Angularjs how to parse ASCII

Tags: angularjs, ascii

Whats a good way to parse ASCII code in Angularjs?

When I have:

```
$scope.title = 'Bezig met verifi&euml;ren...';
```

I get as output:

```
 Bezig met verifi&euml;ren...
```

instead of

> Bezig met verifiëren..

.

Comment: You shouldn't have that in the first place.  You should only use HTML entities in HTML; otherwise, use the actual character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)