# change the included html file on click using angular

Tags: php, html, angularjs

is there an angular way to change the name of the file from which im displaying the content in the main tag? right now im just using the php include function:

```
<main>
   <?php include 'hello.html';?>
</main>
```

but is there a "angulary" solution to change the hello.html file to be lets say...goodbye.html?

Comment: This could help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is simple. but I don't understand your scenario and I'm not able to show you with PHP technology.

Use following way,

Index.html

```
  <main ng-init="loadPage()">
    <div ng-include="{{url}}">

    <div>
  </main>
```

Index.js

```
appModuleName.Controller("index",function($scope){  //appModumodleName is the name of your angular app module

    $scope.loadPage=function()
    { 
      // User your logic to get your desired HTML page url.....

      $scope.url="hello.html"; //or path toward your hello.html
    }
});
```

any query feel free to ask questions...
Hope I'd help...