# Output HTML in Angular, from C# Controller

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

I have some HTML being built in my C# controller, and I'm feeding it into the result to be used on an Angular page. It gets to the page, but when it does, the html is unencoded, and shows up as text, not html.

In the C#:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
    {
        return HandleRequest(() =>
        {
            var customer = _csa.GetCustomer(id);

            var bc = (isMobile) ? string.Empty : CreateBreadCrumbDisplay(id);

            return new
            {
                customer,
                bc
            };
        });
    }
```

In the html:

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-hide="history.bc == null || history.bc.length == 0">
     <div class="span12">
        {{history.bc}}
    </div>
</div>
```

What appears on the page:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb"><li><a href="/Employee#!Search">Employee Dashboard</a> <span class='divider'>/</span></li><li class='active'>Customer Information and History</li></ul>
```

What should appear:

- [Employe Dashboard](http://Employe%20Dashboard)
- Customer Information and History

(but styled by Bootstrap so it's a nice Breadcrumb, and not visually an actual bulleted list)

So, basically, I need to know if there's a way in the html to tell it to display history.bc as actual HTML, and not as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `$sce.trustAsHtml(myhtml)` to wrap your data, angular disallows this otherwise.  Then you need to use the `ng-bind-html` in your html, bound to the variable you've use the `trustAshtml` function on.
Something like:

```
vm.bcHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(myhtml);

<div ng-bind-html="vm.bcHtml"></div>
```

Note you'll need to inject the $sce service.

[Angular JS Api - $sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Here's some info on ng-bind-html.

[Angular JS Api - ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Finally, you'll need to use the angular `$compile` service to register inclusion in the angular pipeline.  Here's a SO post that describes it well.  They use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`, but I believe the preferred method is the one I described above.

[Compiling dynamic HTML strings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database)

Comment: Well, this helped, but perhaps not quite in the way that you intended. The key was that ng-bind. I read up on that a bit, and by simply putting this tag in place of the `{{history.bc}}`, I was able to get it to work right away: `<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="history.bc"></div>`

Comment: If you're using Angular 1.2+, ng-bind-html-unsafe has been deprecated.  It is, by it's own definition, unsafe.  I'd strongly suggest you go the $sce and ng-bind-html route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: The codebase we're in at the moment, actually, is 1.1. We're planning the upgrade, but it's "down the road" still.