# ng-sanitize is not returning with html tags

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I want to display the description users made in the website with ng-repeat. I use php at backend and before inserting the record i used

```
$credentials['description']=htmlentities($credentials['description'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

So my description is converts the html tags and stored as

//This is stored in my database.

```
&lt;h1&gt;I am typing this&lt;/h1&gt;

&lt;p&gt;asldkfjlsjfliwanfewlkl&lt;/p&gt;
```

//When i output this with angularjs

```
<h1>I am typing this</h1> <p>asldkfjlsjfliwanfewlkl</p>
```

Please note  my h1 tags are not stripped off.

//Below is my ng-repeat.

```
   <tr ng-repeat="enquiry in pending">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td><span ng-bind-html="enquiry.description"></span></td>
        </tr>
```

How do i get my h1 tags active.

**Update 1**

```
adminpanel = angular.module('administrator', ['ngMessages','ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ngCookies','ngSanitize','ui.tinymce','flow']);
```

I added a filter for $sce as commented

```
adminpanel.filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
return function (text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
}; 

}])
```

And updated the ng-repeat as

```
<td><span ng-bind-html="enquiry.description | html"></span></td>
```

Now the output is same.

```
<h1>I am typing this</h1> <p>asldkfjlsjfliwanfewlkl</p>
```

Comment: You also need to use $sce   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: Did you correctly added module to your app? `angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);`