# Creating angular directive to reuse code - parse error while creating html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following the code snippet of the control that I am creating. This control is used in various places and the variables differ.

I am trying to write a directive to clean up code, but getting a parse error while inserting values near {{}}.

New to angular and not able to pin point what is it that I am missing. Please help.

track-edit is another directive.

**Original control code:**

```
<div id="text-wrapper">
                    <div track-edit="true" id="Type1Desc_{{t1Card.id}}" class="textbody" ng-blur="SaveDesc('Type1Desc_'+t1Card.id,t1Card.Description,'Type1')">
                        <div>
                            <p><div spellcheck="true"  ng-bind-html="t1Card.OrigDescription|diff:t1Card.Description"></div></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Directive code**

```
app.directive('customEditor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            fId: "@",
            idAppend: "@",
            className: "@",
            origVal: "@",
            currVal: "@"
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: false
        template: ' <div id="text-wrapper"><div track-edit="true" id="{{idAppend}}_{{fId}}" ' +
        'class="{{className}}" ><div><p>' +
        '<div spellcheck="true"  ng-bind-html="{{origVal}}|diff:{{currVal}}"></div></p></div></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
});
```

**Html after directive:**

```
 <custom-editor fid="{{t1Card.id}}" idappend="Type1Desc" classname="textbody" ng-blur="SaveLineItemDesc('Type1Desc_'+t1Card.id,t1Card.Description,'Type1')" origVal="{{t1Card.OrigDescription}}" currVal="{{t1Card.Description}}">
 </custom-editor>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is in this part:

```
fId: "@",
idAppend: "@",
className: "@",
origVal: "@",
currVal: "@"
```

It should be:

```
fid: "@",
idappend: "@",
classname: "@",
origVal: "@",
currVal: "@"
```

And in the directive:

```
<custom-editor fid="{{t1Card.id}}" idappend="Type1Desc" classname="textbody" ng-blur="SaveLineItemDesc('Type1Desc_'+t1Card.id,t1Card.Description,'Type1')" origVal="{{t1Card.OrigDescription}}" currVal="{{t1Card.Description}}">
 </custom-editor>
```

You have **idappend** but you are referring as **idAppend**, which is wrong. You should refer to it as **idappend**.
Same is applicable to **fid** and **classname** which should refer as it is with no camelcase format

EDIT CODE-

If you trusting **origVal** and **currVal**  value then replace this statement :

```
ng-bind-html="{{origVal}}|diff:{{currVal}}"
```

with this one

```
ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{origVal}}|diff:{{currVal}}"
```

Or you can use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)  like this one

```
$sce.parseAsHtml(your_data_value)
```

For more you can refer this one also.
[With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Comment: Note that idAppend would refer to id-append.

Comment: @Billy you are right. Here is sample code http://plnkr.co/edit/vP7wF03DJ0HP8w6953so?p=preview

Comment: Changed to no camelcase, Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{origval}}|diff:{{currval}}] starting at [{origval}}|diff:{{currval}}]

Comment: Can you share the code for which produce origval  and currval ?

Comment: I have updated code.Please check this.It will solve your problem.