# Render HTML content in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following template:

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlist">
```

```
  <div class="list list-inset">
      <div class="item item-divider item-text-wrap">
          {{post.titulo}}
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <img src="{{post.image}}" width="100%" />
      </div>
      <div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;text-align:right">
          {{post.fecha}} - By: {{post.autor}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
          {{ post.contenido }}
      </div>
  </div>
```

The question is that '**post.contenido**' has HTML that I wish to be displayed as it should but it only show the HTML tags and text.

What can I do to render such content?

Kind regards.

Comment: You could try using the ion-view tag and inject a html template to it.

Comment: Can't figure out what you mean. any example?

Comment: Ok, After looking around a little bit, ignore my first comment. Did you try some thing like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html

Comment: do you need double data-binding for contenido var? If yes create a directive if not more easy but not angular friendly use JQUERY :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a scope variable with html in it !

```
$scope.someHTML = "<h1>Big Nice Title here</h1>";
```

You should be able to output it as so

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="someHTML"></div>
```

..in your case it should be like this

```
[...]
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html-unsafe="post.contenido"></div>
[...]
```

Comment: It's been solved using the directive 'ng-bind-html' instead of 'ng-bind-html-unsafe'.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should change your code to:
`<div class="item item-text-wrap" [innerHTML]="post.contenido"> 
  </div>`

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Glad to hear that :D

Answer (score 1):

works for me without unsafe..
so the solution is

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html="post.contenido">
```