# Set HTML as default value of undefined variable in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable that could be potentially unset like this

```
{{salesperson || 'not set'}}
```

I want to add a CSS class to the not set area like this

```
{{salesperson || '<span class="error">- Not Set -</span>'}}
```

When I tried that it throws syntax errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML in expressions is escaped by angular, to avoid HTML/JS injections.

Use ng-class:

```
<span ng-class="{error: !salesperson}">{{salesperson || 'not set'}}</span>
```

Or simply ng-show/ng-hide:

```
<span ng-hide="salesperson" class="error">not set</span>
<span ng-show="salesperson">{{ salesperson }}</span>
```

Comment: This is good. You may need to use `ng-cloak` to prevent "not set" from flickering on the screen on load.

Answer (score 1):

So if you really, really want to inject HTML, look at this question: [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

But if you just want to show an error if it's not defined:

```
{{salesperson}}<span ng-if="!salesperson" class="error ng-cloak">- Not Set -</span>'
```

It will only show the span if `salesperson` is undefined. Make sure to define your `ng-cloak` css as well to prevent any flickering.