# treat angularjs $scope object as html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do i treat angularjs $scope object as html in div. My html code is

{{topicDesc}}

and am passing topicDesc using

```
var topicdesc1 = "Please ensure you read through <a href="http://adajprod.nce.amadeus.net/ABCHelp/pages/faq_home.html" target="_blank">ABC FAQ </a> and <a href="http://adajprod.nce.amadeus.net/ABCHelp/pages/help_home.html" target="_blank">ABC Help</a> before opening a request."`
$scope.topicDesc = topicDesc1;
```

The scope.topicdesc is treated as string and it prints the same exact sentence on webpage. How do i solve this issue? Please help as am a fresher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ng-bind-html-unsafe is the not the right way of doing it as it has been deprecated in higher versions. [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html) would be the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind this html into view with angular method ng-bind-html.
It should be like  this:

```
var topicdesc1 = "Please ensure you read through <a href="http://adajprod.nce.amadeus.net/ABCHelp/pages/faq_home.html" target="_blank">ABC FAQ </a> and <a href="http://adajprod.nce.amadeus.net/ABCHelp/pages/help_home.html" target="_blank">ABC Help</a> before opening a request."`
$scope.topicDesc = topicDesc1;
```

and

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="topicDesc"></div
```

Also see this, Insert HTML into view using angular [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

Comment: Should i define unsafe?