# angular js ng-html inside ng-repeat won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html

I'm using AngularJS with a third party service that generates html responses. I want to use `ng-repeat` to render the HTML responses as a list, however Angular is not showing it

I've created this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7vLa0bx/) to demonstrate my issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s7vLa0bx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a filter for trusting the content

```
<div ng-bind-html="myData | trustAs"></div>
```

```
angular.module('app').filter('trustAs', ['$sce', 
    function($sce) {
        return function (input, type) {
            if (typeof input === "string") {
                return $sce.trustAs(type || 'html', input);
            }
            console.log("trustAs filter. Error. input isn't a string");
            return "";
        };
    }
]);
```

original answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34783962/3769965

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/LL5mr7tw/1/

Comment: ng-bind-html-unsafe was removed from AngularJS sine 1.2.x. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25679834

Comment: we can use `ng-bind-html` with trust filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml