# & in my JSON is rendered as &amp; in Angular view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, special-characters, angular-translate

I have a json file used to store my key/strings for localization using angular-translate. There is a string 'Profile & Preferences' that I am using in my view. When I add that string by using ng-bind-html the string is displaying as:

Profile & Preferences

I thought that ng-bind-html was supposed to convert that to an &. How do I get it to display an `&` instead of `&amp;`? I tried changing the string value in my json to `&amp;` but then it just displays as:

Profile `&amp;amp;` Preferences

Here is the tag I'm using:

```
<h3 ng-bind="'REGISTRATION_3.profile-preferences' | translate"></h3>
```

I have also tried the suggestions in [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html) .

When I used a filter suggested in the above linked question:

```
  app.filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };    
}]);
```

I get this as a result:

```
Profile &amp;amp; Preferences
```

I have also verified that I am injecting 'ngSanitize' in my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, I was typing too quick and tabbed when 'ng-bind' was selected instead of 'ng-bind-html'. My mistake.

What worked was using this filter in app.js:

```
  app.filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
    return function (text) {
        console.log('text is ');
        console.log(text);
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };    
}]);
```

and using it in my tag like this:

```
<h3 ng-bind-html="'REGISTRATION_3.profile-preferences' | translate | html"></h3>
```