# How to compile HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In **controller** bind same data like  `$scope.name = "<div>geetha teko</div>",` this name will now binded to html like `{{name}}`, it is printing like this in browser.`"<div>geetha tek0</div>"`, how can get only `'geetha tek0'` in browser with html tags.

I tried bellow please help any one.

**html code**

```
<div>
    <p> my name is: {{name}}</p>
</div>
```

**angularjs**

```
<script>
   function MyCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.html = "<div> ramesh bogandla</div>"
   }
</script>
```

you can check on jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10127/

Comment: looks like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database

Answer (score 0):

I updated your JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10129/.

Use the following:

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></span>
```

Or for what you have in your question rather than the JSFiddle you provided:

```
<p> my name is: <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></span></p>
```

[Here's some further information that might be handy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Comment: it is not working when update with button please help me ,i update in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10136/

Comment: Since this answered your original question, please mark this as the answer.  I will continue to help you.

Comment: ok i will make, but i update now it is not working, how can do please help me

Comment: please help me update in jsfiddle now it not working same thing i done  http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10136/

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: i accept please help me updated code is not working http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10153/

Comment: Instructions for "accepting" an answer...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work